# How to break new line on Microsoft Sharepoint list column description?

Tags: json, sharepoint

Not sure if this is a good place to ask but I’m about an hour into editing a Sharepoint for the first time, have zero prior knowledge on creating/editing Sharepoints, and I’m stuck trying to figure out how to wrap text to a new line in the description field of a particular column on my list.

We need the submitters to stop at a certain point and not touch the remaining fields, and the only way I can figure out how to do that is by adding a column description that tells them to stop. I want the description of that column to read as:

**————-—STOP ————-—**

**Submitters stop here. Do not use the fields below, unless attaching images/files. The remaining fields are for macro champ use only.**

**———————————————-**

Instead of :

————-—STOP ————-—Submitters stop here. Do not use the fields below, unless attaching images/files. The remaining fields are for macro champ use only.———————————————-

Do I need to use JSON to achieve this? If so..what is the code I would need to use?

Also open to alternative solutions to create a line/stop/hide fields from them or something.

——————
ETA - photo of what my column formatting box looks like.

[image: column formatting]

——————

ETA for further clarification -

The column in particular that I am trying to add the “stop” message to is actually named “Attachments included?” And has ‘yes’ or ‘no’ radio choice buttons. Then the *description* underneath that column says “submitters stop here, unless attaching images/files below.” This column, and it’s description, are hidden from the list overview and only visible when submitting a +New item.

The reason for doing this is because we have a handful of fields towards the end of the +New item submission form that we don’t want submitters to touch, as they are for the help desk agents to fill out only.

I don’t see any other way to add a stop/line or hide certain fields from the submitters (while still leaving them visible to the help desk team), so just trying to make this “stop” description look a little neater.

Answer (score 0):

Format the column as shown below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": " ————-—STOP ————-— \n\n Submitters stop here. Do not use the fields below, unless attaching images/files. The remaining fields are for macro champ use only. \n\n ———————————————",
  "style": {
    "width": "100%",
    "font-weight": "bold"
  }
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: My field to edit the column formatting looks different than the screenshot you posted. I copied the code you provided into my custom json field, but I don’t see any changes applied. I edited my post to include a photo of what my column formatting box looks like, not sure if I need to do something different.

Comment: Drag the column position to the right to compare the results

Comment: hmm okay I see what you’re talking about now but that’s not quite what I’m looking for. Sorry, I didn’t explain my question very well. I will update the post.

Comment: Thank you for your update, from your description, it seems that you want to hide some column based on another column value, yes or no, right? For your requirement, please refer to this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide

Comment: Hi, thank you for sharing that info. I’m still not sure if that’s what I’m looking for, but it’s highly possible I just don’t know what I’m doing well enough to apply it to my scenario correctly. The article you shared seems centered around hiding columns from the Sharepoint list overview, however, what I am looking for is the customization of the actual entry fields (input boxes)  whenever someone is submitting a +New item. We want to prevent submitters from altering specific fields. I’m referring to the settings under list settings -> columns

Answer (score 0):

it does not work in modern SharePoint Online lists/columns.

You can add line breaks easily, when you modify the column in list settings, but it will not show up anymore later when rendered below the actual field, then all line breaks are removed.

You could update the CSS of the page / description fields with
"white-space: pre-line;", then the line breaks that you added before in the editor will show up again, but by default, in the edit forms, they are not rendered. :(

.. or you could switch back to classic mode, there, line breaks in column descriptions also show up again.

See also
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-put-a-line-break-in-a-description-of-a/d2f910e9-39ed-481e-a8dc-29c287a97d78

By the way, when you enter line breaks in the browser in the description, they are retrieved via PowerShell as **&#xD;&#xA;** in the text.
Nevertheless, it is not possible to "set-npnfield" the value of a column description of a column in the same way, the ampersand will get escaped, so you should probably rather store the description string with a real line break in powershell.

A similar problem exists here:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123669/new-line-break-in-sharepoint-column-description

From my understanding, the custom formatter does not change rendering of column description. Maybe have a look in customizing the view instead ...(?)

A more SharePoint-Way to accomplish, what you want to do might be, that you create a default content type with a few columns, then you create an inherited content type that has additional columns in the same list. The Submitters fill out the few columns. After that, you (or a power automate workflow) could change the content type to the one with more columns.